# How to define a cross product of two orthogonal vectors?

Tags: symbolic

`t[s]`, `n[s]` and `b[s]` are three orthogonal vectors. I define a cross product `Cross[t[s], n[s]] = b[s]`. I want to calculate the cross product in the formula `a2`, I want `a2` to have the same result as `a3`. How to achieve this?

[image: Cross product of two unknown orthogonal vectors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `UpValues` for `n` gives desired result:

```
n /: Cross[(a_. t[s]), n[s]] := a b[s]

(2 q[s] T1) t[s]\[Cross]n[s]
(* 2 T1 b[s] q[s] *)

(2 t[s] q[s] T1)\[Cross]n[s]
(* 2 T1 b[s] q[s] *)
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer!

Comment: If you like answer you can accept it, but of course I do not insist.